# In the linux top program, what does the z option indicate

Tags: linux, process-monitoring

I'm trying to understand the top program better, and I don't really get the 'z' option which highlights all running processes.

Wouldn't all processes in top be considered running?
In what context would a process be listed in top but not considered running?

Comment: Way off-topic for SO; belongs on [su] or [unix.se]

Comment: Opened in Super User http://superuser.com/questions/675124/in-the-linux-top-program-what-does-the-z-option-indicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is off-topic and should be elsewhere. But then again, maybe this helps to formulate better question in Unix & Linux or Super User.

Assume that you have a computer which has only one central processing unit with only single core. This kind of a computer can not execute programs in parallel, because only one task (that can be a program running in the user space or a kernel task, e.g.) can access the CPU at any one time.

Multitasking operating system kernels, like Linux, let each task access the CPU in turns for a little while, thus making it *seem* that they are running in parallel. In reality tasks are run in a sequential style and only one task is in running state in our fictional toy compyter with just one CPU containing a single core. Other tasks spend most of their time in other states, mostly in TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE but they can also be stopped (with Ctlr-z for example) and so on and so forth.

Things aren't as simple as I've described above in modern computers having multiple CPUs with multiple cores, but the idea still applies: only programs actually running on a core will be in running state, other tasks are in other states which are mostly aggregated to be in sleeping state by top (displayed as 'S').

Comment: Ohhh ok...so the colored tasks are sleeping, and the non-colored tasks are running. Awesome, thanks!